# How can i have a background image and lighting that are crossed with lines drawn on it in CSS

Tags: css

I want to know how this web(http://pixelarity.com/) at the first step coming up with just a background color(with a transition-duration)and after that coming up a text(like last step with a transition-duration) and at the end of coming up with background image and lighting that are crossed with lines drawn on it.
I do not want to use SASS & LESS and just i want to use CSS
If the answer to this question takes a long time, just i want a link or keyword for search that.
Thank you for your answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help you to take a look at the source of the website - this can often show you how a certain effect or way of styling is achieved. If you are unaware of this, specific tools might help you (i.e. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), though all modern browsers also have some form of source code inspection themselves).

In this particular example, it looks as if CSS transitioning effects have been used. If you inspect the code yourself, you can find a div element named "skel-layers-wrapper". It contains the following parameter(s) for CSS animation;

```
transition: top 0.5s ease, right 0.5s ease, bottom 0.5s ease, left 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
```

If you want to learn more about CSS animations, I can advise the developer guide on Mozilla Developer Network. Please read [using CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) on there for more information.